# how to integrate with facebook timeline to share activities?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to integrate with facebook timeline so that each activity on my website gets shared on user's facebook timeline.
i earlier used to use the publish stream permission to publish the activities on user's wall, and a second dialog comes for the publish stream permission while getting signed up on my website.

however i have recently observed that some sites are doing something different, while getting signed up on these sites, you will never get second dialog for publish stream permission and each activity will be shared n fb wall.
will be great if someone could explain me in detail, also i am doing all this in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is Open Graph actions (OG). Instead of 'publish_stream', OG-enabled sites are using 'publish_action' which doesn't require confirmation. All OG actions are published against OG objects, which are usually webpages. Have a look at the introduction to Open Graph at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/, then follow the tutorial at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ to see how to implement it for your site.